# Exclude given value from a for loop - ES5

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a for loop that generates and creates input values based a csv header:

Here is the for loop:

```
for ( var i=0 ; i<fields.length ; i++ ) {
    var field = editor.field( fields[i] );
 
    selectEditor.add( {
        label: field.label(),
        name: field.name(),
        type: 'select',
        options: header,
        def: header[i]
    } );
}
```

the variable `field` contains the following array (depending on the csv header)

```
["firstName", "surname", "gender"]
```

How do I remove key `gender` from the for loop?

I have tried `field.Slice(-3)`

**Solution:**

Using Chrissy's answer I was able to come up with the followig result which solves my issue:

```
var selectEditor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor();
var fields = editor.order();

const filteredArray = fields.filter((fields) => fields !== 'gender')
console.log(filteredArray) <--- new array:: HAY!

for ( var i=0 ; i<filteredArray.length ; i++ ) {
    var field = editor.field( filteredArray[i] );
    selectEditor.add( {
        label: field.label(),
        name: field.name(),
        type: 'select',
        options: header,
        def: header[i]
    } );
}
```

Comment: can you show what is `fields` and `editor` cause i think there is a better practice implementing it

Comment: How about reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)? What problems did you run into? Note that `Slice` ≠ `slice`. What do you expect `field.label()` to do if `field` is the array that you claim it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
const filteredArray = fields.filter((field) => field !== 'gender')
```

First filters elements which return false and returns a new, filtered array.
You could also just skip the field by doing:

```
if(field.includes('gender')) {
  return
}
```

Comment: thank! I mean to just remove gender if gender is found

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it.
You say "field" contains an array. I think you mean "fields" because you use "field" as an object. You want to get rid of the "gender" value, so filter the array if it is not nested in another array there is no reason not to do it, isnt it?

I think filter fits you perfectly. Please give more input of what you are trying to do if not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me comping up with the solution!